# Adobe DPS version 32 - How to hide top and bottom menus that show up when clicking on folio contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-dps

I am working on a canvas application to be used inside an Adobe DPS folio.
At first the canvas element is hidden, and there is a button to activate it over the page content. The button is linked to an event listener:

```
jQuery('#DefaultCanvas')
.on('click', '#startcanvas, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#main,#startcanvas').toggle();
})
```

The problem is, when the user clicks on the button, the top and bottom menus that are part of the DPS app show up for a few seconds, therefore breaking the user experience.
Is there a way (using JavaScript) to block those menus from showing up? Did I miss something on the code above?